# Azure Mobile Services and Asp.net Identity Architecture

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-mobile-services

I am hoping someone can clear up how these things can work together.

I want to be my own identity provider, so in my web api I have an OAuth token provider. I want users to register with me and then be authenticated using my token provider. The idea in the future is that more of my mobile apps and web apps will be accessible using the OAuth login sharing the user's identity.

So, if I use azure mobile services how do I implement the normal asp.net identity stuff?
And, how would a normal web app be able to use the data stored in azure mobile services? Would I have two dbcontexts one for mobile and one for web?

I've been reading and watching a lot of stuff on azure but nothing seems to show how I can do this. Most of it has to do with using external providers like facebook, ms, twitter, etc. I want to be one of those external providers, just not sure how to do it and allow my websites to still use the .net identity data.

If you could point me to or post some example / tutorial / blogs that would be great.

Comment: what did you end up doing, i am also looking for a solution

Comment: I ended up using Thinkecture's identity server 3 and implementing my own custom auth system. Basically their server acts as my IdP and I built my own azure backend to validate their auth token and grab the info and convert it to a a zumo auth token. This link is a thread on their github that explains a bit of what I did and links to a gist of code to do the zumo side and other pieces. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/434

Comment: I should add that I attempted to create a katana middleware but it never worked as I wanted and I also decided that I wanted my solution to offer a way to provide native views on mobile devices instead of doing the "jam a webview login page in there" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a supported scenario, although it isn't documented very well at the moment.

The Mobile Services .NET runtime is built on the ASP.NET [Katana authentication middleware](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/). The mobile service abstracts these middleware using the LoginProvider base class. The authentication model was recently made extensible for situations such as yours. In order to have Mobile Services recognize and use your identity provider, you would have to create your own LoginProvider.

There are currently two examples of this:

1. Adding a Katana middleware as an identity provider - part of [this post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/28/azure-mobile-services-net-updates/).
2. Creating a custom username/password setup - tutorial [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/).

You could certainly use these techniques to wrap the standard ASP.NET identity functionality.

As to your question about accessing the data, there are a variety of approaches. Your web app could treat Mobile Services as a backend and pass through requests. This is basically treating the web app as an additional client platform, peer to your mobile apps. Another option is to, as you said, create multiple DBContexts. While you might get slightly better performance, this comes with a code maintainability tradeoff. It also wouldn't scale well if you build multiple web apps on the same data backend.